# Запятая или точка с запятой

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, точка-с-запятой

Подскажите, пожалуйста, на месте () нужна запятая или лучше точка с запятой? "Во сне мне видится бесконечный цветущий сад() и я всё бегу по нему, всё бегу, и бегу, и бегу". Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

> Запятая или точка с запятой?

Я бы поставил **тире:**

***Во сне мне видится бесконечный цветущий сад — и я всё бегу по нему, всё бегу, и бегу, и бегу...***

> [**§ 114.**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133) Между частями сложносочиненного предложения ставится
>   тире, если вторая часть предложения заключает в себе значение
>   результата, следствия, резкого противопоставления (чаще перед союзом
>   ***и,*** реже перед союзами ***но, а***): Надо успеть записать. *Малейшая задержка  — и мысль, блеснув, исчезнет* (Пауст.); *Сначала я старался не зачерпнуть воды или грязи в туфли, но оступился раз,
>   оступился другой — и стало всё равно* (Сол.)...  *Положишь палочку на
>   воду — и она поплывет по течению* (Пришв.)...

Comment: Слава, кстати, тире в этом случае тоже факультативно. В сложносочиненных предложениях для указания на неожиданное присоединение: Ещё немного (— ,) и мы оказались бы на краю пропасти; (Розенталь).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Т.е. возможны как тире, так и запятая?

Comment: Да, выбор за вами.

Comment: А где здесь "результат, следствие, резкое противопоставление"? И  привет ребятам из 2016 года!   А мне еще "дебютные" надо бы добавить...

Answer (score 2):

Нужна запятая. В сложносочиненном предложении перед союзами **и,да** (в значении «и»), **или** точка с запятой ставится в том случае, когда они  соединяют два предложения, которые без них были бы разделены точкой. 
В вашем случае первая часть сложного предложения не может быть закончена точкой, к тому же оно не достаточно распространено.

Подробно о знаках препинания в сложном предложении можете прочитать здесь: [Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П. СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ  М.: ЧеРо, 1999](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/48.htm)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: **Серж!** Вначале Вы пишете: _Нужна запятая. В сложносочиненном предложении перед союзами **и, да**… запятая ставится в том случае, когда они соединяют два предложения, **которые без них были бы разделены точкой**._ Затем пишете: _В вашем случае первая часть сложного предложения **не может быть закончена точкой**…_  (?) Но если (по-Вашему!) **не может**, какие же тогда основания для запятой?

Comment: Слава, оговорился. Я имел в виду точку с запятой.

Comment: Я тоже за запятую.

Answer (score 2):

"Во сне мне видится бесконечный цветущий сад — и я всё бегу по нему, всё бегу, и бегу, и бегу".

Мне больше нравится вариант с тире, так как две части предложения явно разделяются паузой, а такой вариант запятая не обеспечивает.

Если поставить точку с запятой, то это полная остановка голоса (как в конце предложения), а пауза короткая. Получается, что связь предложений ослаблена, а деления на две части всё равно нет. А такое деление необходимо, так как во второй части своя интонация, связанная с перечислением.

И на письме тире отделяет первую часть от второй части, в которой уже есть запятые.

Answer (score 1):

Всё не так просто с этим предложением. Нужно посмотеть, нет ли здесь общего второстепенного члена для двух частей сложносочинённого предложения. Именно он влияет на знак (или его отсутствие) перед И. Я думаю, что общий второстепенный член  всё-таки есть - обстоятельство *во сне*.

***Во сне*** *мне видится бесконечный цветущий сад и я всё бегу по нему, всё бегу, и бегу, и бегу.*

Обстоятельство  ***"во сне"*** относится к двум предикативным единицам. Поэтому запятую или другой знак перед И ставить не нужно.

Comment: К сожалению, русский язык я знаю не так хорошо, как хотелось бы. Поэтому простите, если вопрос будет звучать глупо, но если бы предложение имело вид: "Во сне **я** вижу бесконечный цветущий сад и **я** все бегу по нему, все бегу, и бегу, и бегу..." Тогда бы тоже запятая была не нужна? "Я" или "мне" тут не имеют значения?

Comment: Тогда тоже запятая была бы не нужна.

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо за ответ. А мне почему-то даже чисто интонационно хотелось поставить здесь знак препинания. Хотелось сделать паузу на этом месте.

Comment: Очень важно, есть здесь общий второстепенный член предложения или нет. Если его нет и "во сне" относится только к первой части, то тогда запятая нужна.

Comment: Хм... интересно. А есть еще такой вариант: "Я закрываю глаза и представляю цветущий сад  () и  я все бегу по нему, бегу и бегу". В таком случае нужна будет запятая на месте ()?

Comment: Екатерина, по поводу запятой немного сомневаюсь. Да, вы правильно заметили: здесь общий второстепенный член. Но у Розенталя есть примечание: При наличии общего второстепенного члена предложения запятая перед союзом и ставится, если союз повторяется: ***В такую погоду и волк не рыщет, и медведь не вылезает из берлоги.***

Comment: У нас ведь тоже повторяется союз. Во сне мне видится бесконечный цветущий сад ***и*** я всё бегу по нему, всё бегу, ***и*** бегу, ***и*** бегу.

Comment: У первого союза И и последующих совершенно разная функция. Первый союз соединяет два предложения.

Comment: Так а в таком случае запятая тоже не нужна: " "Я закрываю глаза и представляю цветущий сад () и я все бегу по нему, все бегу, и бегу, и бегу"?

Comment: Анна, в новом предложении  "Я закрываю глаза и представляю цветущий сад;  и я все бегу по нему, бегу и бегу" уже можно ставить знак между частями, потому что общего второстепенного члена у них нет..

Comment: И в новом предложении лучше ставить точку с запятой? Или и запятая возможна?

Comment: Запятая тоже возможна, но я делаю значительную паузу после первого предложения, да и запятая во второй части уже есть; поэтому предпочла бы точку с запяттой.

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо вам за помощь!